# SSD errors under NetApp E-Series 5424

Tags: logging, ssd, netapp

We're having some weird issues with our Storage (netapp e-series 5425) and a bunch of SSDs.

Technically they work fine, we can do all operations on it, whatever runs on it runs fine, but we keep getting these messages in the log (for all drives):

```
Date/Time: 11/11/18 5:59:38 AM
Sequence number: 2043
Event type: 100A
Event category: Error
Priority: Informational
Event needs attention: false
Event send alert: false
Event visibility: true
Description: Drive returned CHECK CONDITION
Event specific codes: 1/1c/0
Component type: Drive
Component location: Tray 99, Slot 15
Logged by: Controller in slot A

Raw data:
4d 45 4c 48 03 00 00 00 fb 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0a 10 11 20 2a a9 e7 5b 0e 00 01 00 0a 01 00 00 
00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 
01 00 00 00 63 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
0a 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
01 00 00 00 01 00 00 04 58 00 00 00 14 00 0d 01 
70 00 01 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00 
00 00 c9 1c 20 00 0e 81 cc dd bb 37 00 0a 00 00 
00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 0e 81 00 00 00 00 
10 00 43 87 50 01 e8 20 02 6c 8e 48 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

We tried to "decode" them using the documentation provided here https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1072437/~/how-to-manually-decode-ddes-in-the-mel- but the message format simply seems to be different, so we haven't had much luck.

The firmware we have running is:

```
  FIRMWARE INVENTORY                                          
   SANtricity®                                                
      AMW Version:              11.20.0G00.0020                
      Report Date:              Mon Nov 12 23:37:57 EET 2018  

   Storage Array                                              
      Storage Array Name:       fsan01                        
      Current Package Version:  08.20.05.00                    
      Current NVSRAM Version:   N5468-820834-DB1              
      Staged Package Version:   None                          
      Staged NVSRAM Version:    None                          

   Controllers                                                
      Location:                 Tray 99, Slot A                
      Current Package Version:  08.20.05.00                    
      Current NVSRAM Version:   N5468-820834-DB1              
      Board ID:                 5468                          
      Sub-Model ID:             179                            

      Location:                 Tray 99, Slot B                
      Current Package Version:  08.20.05.00                    
      Current NVSRAM Version:   N5468-820834-DB1              
      Board ID:                 5468                          
      Sub-Model ID:             179                            

   Power Supplies                                              
      Location:                 Tray 99 Left                  
      Firmware Version:         02.47                          

      Location:                 Tray 99 Right                  
      Firmware Version:         02.47
```

All the drives under it are:

```
   Drive      
      Tray, Drawer, Slot:     Manufacturer:     Product ID:          Drive Type:                    Capacity:      Drive firmware version:     FPGA Version: (SSD only)
      Tray 99, Slot 1         Pliant            LB806MC              Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)     739.712 GB     MS07                        Not Available
```

We are at a loss on what do these DDEs mean, and we currently don't have a contract with NetApp for support.

Could anyone shed some light?

Comment: If a drive ever completely fails, open a ticket and Netapp will send you another one.